# Batch processing requests

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a service which receives many requests and I am trying to optimize it by aggregating requests in batches and then processing batch which is much quicker than processing requests one by one. That worked better than expected and I decided to try and make this batch processor generic.

Here is code for `BatchCollection` class which exposes methods `AddItem` which is fire-and-forget and `ProcessAsync` which adds item to batch and can be awaited when batch is processed.

```
public delegate void BatchEventHandler<TItem>(BatchCollection<TItem> sender, EventArgs args);

public abstract class BatchCollection<TItem> : IDisposable
{
    public event BatchEventHandler<TItem> BatchEvent;

    private IList<TItem> items;
    private readonly int batchItemCount;
    private readonly object syncObj = new object();
    private bool disposed = false;
    private SemaphoreSlim requestSemaphore;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public BatchCollection(int batchItemCount)
    {
        if (batchItemCount <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("batchItemCount", batchItemCount, "batchItemCount greater than 0.");
        }

        this.items = new List<TItem>();
        this.batchItemCount = batchItemCount;
        requestSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    }

    public void AddItem(TItem item)
    {
        int itemsCount;
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            itemsCount = AddItemInternal(item);
        }

        OnBatchEvent(itemsCount);
    }

    public async Task ProcessAsync(TItem item)
    {
        Task processingTask;
        int itemsCount;
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            itemsCount = AddItemInternal(item);
            processingTask = requestSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        }

        OnBatchEvent(itemsCount);
        await processingTask;
    }

    public void ProcessItems()
    {
        SemaphoreSlim localSemaphore = null;
        List<TItem> toProcess = null;
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            if (items.Count != 0)
            {
                toProcess = new List<TItem>(items);

                // allow new requests to be added while current are being processed
                items.Clear();
                localSemaphore = requestSemaphore;
                requestSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
            }
        }

        if (toProcess != null) // if (items.Count != 0)
        {
            ProcessBatch(toProcess);
            localSemaphore.Release(toProcess.Count);
            localSemaphore.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        // disallow adding of new requests and process all pending requests
        disposed = true;
        ProcessItems();
        requestSemaphore.Dispose();
        BatchEvent = null; // unsubscribe everyone so we don't have memory leaks
    }

    public abstract void ProcessBatch(IList<TItem> items);

    private int AddItemInternal(TItem item)
    {
        // this should always be called from inside lock (syncObj)
        if (disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
        }

        items.Add(item);
        return items.Count;
    }

    private void OnBatchEvent(int itemCount)
    {
        if (itemCount != batchItemCount)
        {
            return;
        }

        var handlers = BatchEvent; // for thread safety reasons
        if (handlers != null)
        {
            BatchEvent(this, null); // TODO: event arguments
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `BatchProcessor` which calls `ProcessItems` method on `BatchCollection`.

```
public class BatchProcessor<TItem> : IDisposable
{
    protected BatchCollection<TItem> collection;
    private int aggregateDelay;
    private int afterProcessingDelay;
    private Thread processingThread;
    private SemaphoreSlim pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore;
    private volatile bool disposed = false;

    public BatchProcessor(BatchCollection<TItem> collection, int aggregateDelay, int afterProcessingDelay = 0)
    {
        if (aggregateDelay < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("aggregateDelay", aggregateDelay, "aggregateDelay must be a positive number.");
        }

        if (afterProcessingDelay < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("afterProcessingDelay", afterProcessingDelay, "afterProcessingDelay must be a positive number.");
        }

        if (collection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
        }

        this.collection = collection;
        this.aggregateDelay = aggregateDelay;
        this.afterProcessingDelay = afterProcessingDelay;
        pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
        this.collection.BatchEvent += OnBatchEvent;
        processingThread = new Thread(ProcessingLoop);
        processingThread.Start();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        disposed = true;
        this.collection.BatchEvent -= OnBatchEvent;
        SafelyReleaseSemaphore(pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore);
        processingThread.Join();
        pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnBatchEvent(BatchCollection<TItem> sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        SafelyReleaseSemaphore(pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore);
    }

    private void SafelyReleaseSemaphore(SemaphoreSlim sem)
    {
        lock (sem)
        {
            if (sem.CurrentCount == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    sem.Release();
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    // could potentially happen if unsubscribe from event (in Dispose) but BatchCollection already saved reference with this subscriber before invoking event
                }
                catch (SemaphoreFullException)
                {
                    // could potentially happen if Dispose and OnBatchEvent get called at the same time
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessingLoop()
    {
        while (!disposed)
        {
            int sleepTime;
            if (!pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore.Wait(0)) // check if there is work now
            {
                pendingItemsForProcessingSemaphore.Wait();
                sleepTime = aggregateDelay;
            }
            else
            {
                sleepTime = afterProcessingDelay;
            }

            if (disposed)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (sleepTime > 0) // avoid context switching
            {
                Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            }

            collection.ProcessItems();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome! Also, is there any existing library that does something like this?

Answer (score 1):

We use this approach for group commit, ie writing a batch of operations to disk instead of flushing one at a time. Our implementation is a wrapper around BlockingCollection which handles almost all of the synchronization.

So my suggestion is consider using BlockingCollection and here is an example of what that could look like:

```
public class Batcher<T> : IDisposable
{    
    public const int DefaultMaxBatchSize = 1000;
    private readonly int _maxBatchSize;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _items;
    private readonly Task _batchTask;

    public Batcher(int maxBatchSize = DefaultMaxBatchSize, int? boundedCapacity = null)
    {
        _maxBatchSize = maxBatchSize;
        _items = new BlockingCollection<T>(boundedCapacity ?? int.MaxValue);
        _batchTask = Task.Run((Action)ProcessItems);
    }

    public delegate void BatchHandler(IEnumerable<T> items);

    public event BatchHandler OnBatch;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _items.CompleteAdding();
        _batchTask.Wait();
    }

    private void ProcessItems()
    {
        var buffer = new List<T>(_maxBatchSize);
        while (!_items.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (_items.TryTake(out var firstItem, 1000))
            {
                buffer.Add(firstItem);
                while (buffer.Count < _maxBatchSize && _items.TryTake(out var item))
                {
                    buffer.Add(item);
                }

                OnBatch?.Invoke(buffer);
                buffer.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why the downvote? please provide some feedback so I can improve the answer!